# Weblogic Installer will not hook the Java Virtual Machine to load the installer

Tags: java, weblogic

Getting the following error when attempting to load the Oracle Weblogic installer:

tsugonko-1:  ~/weblogic
→ **java -jar fmw_12.2.1.4.0_wls_quick.jar**
Launcher log file is /private/var/folders/jk/jjhksz9n6c354s25_pvj9qp80000gn/T/OraInstall2022-01-13_11-44-45AM/launcher2022-01-13_11-44-45AM.log.
Extracting the installer . . . . Done
Checking if CPU speed is above 300 MHz.   Actual 2662.4 MHz    Passed

Checking swap space: must be greater than 512 MB.   Actual 145636 MB    Passed

Checking if this platform requires a 64-bit JVM.   Actual 64    Passed

Checking temp space: must be greater than 300 MB.   Actual 145636 MB    Passed

Preparing to launch the Oracle Universal Installer from /private/var/folders/jk/jjhksz9n6c354s25_pvj9qp80000gn/T/OraInstall2022-01-13_11-44-45AM
Unrecognized option: -d64

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

**1. First, I have verified that the installer script is present, but don't know how to verify that it is actually loading**:
tsugonko-1:  /private/var/folders/jk/jjhksz9n6c354s25_pvj9qp80000gn/T/OraInstall2022-01-13_11-44-45AM
→ ls
OPatch                            launcher2022-01-13_11-44-45AM.log oui
**install13817544693051062390.sh**    oracle_common

**2. I believe my $JAVE_HOME path is correct:**

→ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home

→ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home/bin

(*notice that "bin" is not included in the /usr/libexec path, I removed the /bin from the $JAVA_HOME path, but that did not correct the issue)*

**3. And I believe I have correctly listed the PATH in the ~/.bash_profile** (Mac OS, no .bashrc, amended file output to the actual PATH variable

tsugonko-1:  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
→ cat ~/.bash_profile
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home/bin

export PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH

export ORACLE_HOME=~/Applications/Oracle

(*Notice I have two variable paths, I commented one out then the other, but this did not correct the issue either)*, internet search suggested both, but I assume one is **best practice)**

Any suggestions from the group?  Incidentally, I did have weblogic server installer, but it got corrupted: I could load the admin server, but not any managed servers, so I deleted the files (**rm -rf weblogic)**.
Is it possible I did not properly uninstall weblogic and there is a zombied process preventing the installer to hook the JVM or otherwise not load?

Comment: FORGOT TO MENTION: I do now have multiple copies of jdk (16.0.2 & 17.0.1), I updated to see if it would correct issue which it did not.  Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: Found someone who has an Oracle support license which suggested the "Unrecognized option: -d64" error was due to a special char in the file path.  So I moved the installer out of Home, '~' and created a new folder in /Users/weblogic.  That didn't correct issue, so I moved one of the jdks into this folder which also did not correct the issue

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic Server 12.2.1.4 does not support java 16 but only java 8 and java 11.
Also, it is only supported with Oracle JDK and not OpenJDK.

Comment: Thank Emmanuel, much appreciate your time reading this post.